# PHP move_uploaded_file not uploading

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload an image on blog but it just doesn't do it. No error mesgs, just doesn't upload it. Checked permissions on the folder and they work when i place the image in the images folder but not when adding a post.
Below is the code im using.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$post_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$post_image_temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

$post_content = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['post_content']);
$post_tags = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['post_tags']);
$post_status = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['post_status']);

// $post_comment_count = 4; //THIS NEEDS TO BE DYNAMIC

move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp,"../images/".$post_image) ;
// if(!move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp,"../images/".$post_image)){
//   echo 'Moved successfully:';
// }else{
//   print_r(error_get_last());
// }

$query = "INSERT INTO posts(post_category_id, post_title, post_author, post_date, post_image, post_content, post_tags, post_status)";
$query .= "VALUES ({$post_category_id},'{$post_title}','{$post_author}',now(),'{$post_image}','{$post_content}','{$post_tags}','{$post_status}') ";

      $create_post_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
      confirm($create_post_query);
```

}

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute path (e.g. `"/var/www/your_project/images/".$post_image`) instead of a relative path? Does that give you the same result?

Comment: Inspect the values of $post_image_temp ?  And, did you set the enctype on your form? e.g., `<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: @GeekZinside Can you show me your HTML form please?

Comment: @rickdenhaan - thanks for your response but that did not work.

Comment: @MrProPop - i can't paste the whole code here... it won't fit.

Comment: sorry guys i'm having a little trouble pasting code in here....

Comment: @GeekZinside link your HTML code in codepin or something and paste the link in the comments

Comment: @MrProPop
 I've added the code to github : https://github.com/00crafter00/CMSblog

Comment: @GeekZinside Solved. Check out my answer and try it.

Comment: Your code is doing no error checking of any sort.  You might want to start by implementing some (Look at the error code in the $_FILES array if set, use is_uploaded_file() to check the file you are about to move really is an upload, etc) http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: Additionally, whilst mysqli_real_escape_string() shows you put some thought into avoiding SQL injection it can be bypassed (usually by using pathological input, unexpected character encodings, etc).  You might want to look into adding some additional protection with a prepared statement

Comment: @GordonM
Forgive me as I'm new to PHP. where would I place the code referenced in the link you provided? Also, thank you for the advice on securing the code. I will look into it and make adjustments.

Comment: @GeekZinside The code examples should show you how to use the $_FILES array, how to get the source path, etc

Comment: @GordonM - Thanks GordonM i'll check them out and see if i can figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp,"../images/".$post_image) ;
```

with

```
move_uploaded_file(
    $post_image_temp,
    __DIR__ . "/../images/" . $post_image
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change these

```
move_uploaded_file("$post_image_temp,","../images/" . $post_image) ;
if(!move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp,"../images/".$post_image)){
```

to these

```
move_uploaded_file("$post_image_temp,", "images/" . $post_image) ;
if(move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "images/" . $post_image)){
```

Tested and works fine now!

Comment: I's still not working. Here's my cms file directory
'cmssystem
  *admin
  *css
  *fonts
  *images
  *includes
  *js'

Comment: I'm getting this error message when I inspect the element using F12 in IE.
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: It should work.. Unless you are doing something wrong.

Comment: And it has nothing to do with CSS so check what error you have got and fix them from your side.

Answer (score -1):

you can use below code for acessing images folder

```
move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp,dirname(__FILE__)."/images/".$post_image) ;
```

but you should make sure `images` folder exists in same folder as the php file. If `images` folder is in an higher directory than your php file then use

```
dirname(__FILE__)."../images/"
```